# A question about Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ and $g$ be infinitely differentiable and the domian of $f$ equals to the domian of $g$ (says $D$). Then the following is true:

> If $f(x)=g(x)$ $\forall x$, then $f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)$ $\forall a \in D$ and $\forall n\ge 0$.

Here comes the question:

> If for a particular $a \in D$, $f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)$ $\forall n \ge 0$, can we say that $f(x)=g(x)$?

Any counter example if it is wrong? (**Edit**: this is done!)

**Edit**: how about the newer version?

> If both $f$ and $g$ are [analytic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) and for a particular $a \in D$, $f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)$ $\forall n \ge 0$, can we say that $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: Your assumption of continuity is, at best, superfluous: continuity follows from derivability, and you're assuming $\,f,g\;$ are infinitely differentiable...

Answer (score 1):

If $\,f(x)=g(x)\;\;\forall\,x\;$ then the functions are identically the very same function, so the derivatives' equality is trivial.

On the other hand we have

$$f(x)=1\;,\;\;g(x)=2\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a)=0\;\;\forall\,a\;\wedge\;\forall\,n>0 $$

yet $\,f(x)\neq g(x)\;$ ...

If you insist in also having $\,f(a)=f^{(0)}(a)=g^{(0)}(a)=g(a)\,$ for some $\,a\,$, then David's example is on the money.

Comment: He is saying for every $n\geq0$.

Comment: Thanks @MhenniBenghorbal , edited.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $f(x)=\cases{e^{-1/x^2}, & $x\ne0$\cr 0,&$x=0$ }$. One can verify that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and that $f$ and all of its derivatives take the value $0$ at $x=0$.

Of course, the zero function also has these properties.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution.